# Ubuntu 14.04.2 wireless not working on Macbook Pro9.2 from bootable USB

Tags: 14.04, wireless, live-usb, macbook-pro

I need help on creating Bootable Ubuntu on Mac! I just created a bootable USB on Mac using ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso. It works. But I have two issues with it:

1. There are two partitions titled "efi" appeared when booting from the USB flash drive, instead of one. I can boot into Ubuntu from both partitions. Upon inspection, one is called “bootx64.efi”, another “grubx64.efi”.
2. My wireless network doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS amd64. I am running it live from USB drive. It will only use plug-in Ethernet.

My laptop: MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012), MacBookPro9,2, MD101LL/A, 13.3"/2.5 i5/2x4GB/500-5400, Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite

USB drive: UFD 3.0 Silicon-Power 16G USB device (it has U3 software on it before format) formatted with “Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and GUID, one partition only”.

On Macbook Pro 13 Mid-2012 i5 2.5Hz, since wireless not working, I issued a lspci command on Mac and got response as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci –nm | grep 0280

02:00.0 “0280” “14e4” “4331” –r02 “1066” “00f5”
```

I then booted this Ubuntu USB on my Windows 7 PC Lenovo ThinkPad T410 i5 2.4GHz (2010) with legacy BIOS/MBR. It is bootable as well, wow! And the wireless works flawlessly. I also issued lspci as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci –nm | grep 0280

03:00.0 “0280” “8086” “4239” –r35 “8086” “1311”
```

In response to Jeremy31's answer, I booted Ubuntu 14.04.2 again off the live USB on my MacBook Pro9.2 without installation. The wireless had no reaction as it was. I then used an Ethernet cable direct connecting my Mac to my modem. It connected the Ubuntu to the internet fine through wired connection.

I typed the command you suggested: `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`. But it gave out an error message: `E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer`.

I never get to your modprobe command of course.

Jeremy31,

I did `sudo apt-get update` using wired connection without any issue. I then issued `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`. I still gave out the same error: `E: Unable to locate package firmware-b43-installer`.

Any other trick?

Thanks, Josh

Comment: 14e4:4331 is a Broadcom chip, you could use the "Additional Driver" utility to install the proprietary driver for it after you have Ubuntu installed.

Answer (score 0):

The Mac will likely only be able to use wifi after installing to a drive and using `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and rebooting.  You could try the same command using the Live version along with `sudo modprobe -r b43` followed by `sudo modprobe b43` but it usually hangs

Burning the ISO to a USB drive is different than installing it.  If I misunderstood your post, I apologize

The Live version works with the Lenovo because it has an Intel wifi card and Ubuntu is able to distribute the firmware with the install disk and not need a seperate download like the Mac needs with the Broadcom wifi

EDIT: Since the normal install method isn't working correctly, download https://www.dropbox.com/s/7exlzch25ap6uha/b43.zip?dl=0 and extract it to your home folder, then

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo mv b43 /lib/firmware
```

reboot

Comment: I installed the Ubuntu to the Mac from this live USB and still didn't get wifi. I issued all these commands as you suggested. After reboot, I still didn't get wifi at all. I then created a Mac bootable Kubuntu live USB. The wifi works on this Kubuntu instatntly without me doing anything, just running live USB. Any inside on this, Broadcom wifi working on Kubuntu, but not Ubuntu? Thanks, Josh